# Passing sparse matrix as argument to non-templated function

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

Is it possible to write a non-templated function that takes as argument an Eigen sparse matrix and be able to pass to it matrices with different template parameters (in particular with different row major/col major storage orders)?

I am aware of the solution using a template function taking a SparseMatrix, but I need this function to be virtual.

Some context about the problem I'm trying to solve:

We have a larger code in which we have recently switched to using Eigen for sparse matrices.  The problem matrix is populated piece-by-piece by various objects (which implement virtual methods that take a reference to that matrix).  Before this happens, the matrix sparsity pattern is pre-computed and the array of inner indices set.  There's a fair number of derived classes that contribute to the problem matrix, some of them user-provided.

We support several (direct and iterative) solvers, including an interface to Pardiso (now through Eigen). Pardiso expects the matrix to have row-major storage and so we currently have hard-coded row-major storage (all other current solvers would work with either storage type).

However, we would like to also expose some of the built-in Eigen direct sparse solvers (such as SuperLU) which expect the matrix to be in column-major form, else they perform a copy.

My question is how to best support both storage types.

Comment: You have a solution you want help with, but what is the problem you intend to solve with that solution? Perhaps there are other solutions? Please read about [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: You may try something based on `std::variant`, but I'm not sure either how this would help. Transposing/copying is really cheap compared to decomposing matrices -- and many solvers need to make a copy anyway.